# Would anyone mind helping me trouble shoot my code, i am trying to import a class i made and get" cannot resolve error"

Tags: java, import

New to java and need some help. I am working with 2 files. One defines a class and all of it's methods and another constructs an instance of this class. My project requires that we write the output from the class methods to a file.When I try to import file 1 into file 2 I keep getting "cannot resolve" error any ideas why?

File #1

```
public class ViolinGonzalezAP3 {
    //Create Violin class
        public int numberOfStrings = 4;
        public char[] stringNames = {'E', 'A', 'D', 'G'};
        public boolean isTuned = false;
        public boolean isPlaying = false;
        public int numberOfViolins = 0;
    class Violin{
        //Create methods for Violin class
        public Violin(){
            numberOfViolins++;
        }
        public void startPlaying() {
            isPlaying = true;
            System.out.println(" violin is now playing.");
        }
        public void stopPlaying() {
            isPlaying = false;
            System.out.println(" violin has stopped playing.");
        }
        public void tuneOn() {
            isTuned = true;
            System.out.println(" violin is now tuned.");
        }
        public void tuneOff() {
            isTuned = false;
            System.out.println(" violin is untuned.");
        } 
        int getNumberOfViolins(){
            return numberOfViolins;
        }
        int getNumberOfStrings(){
            return numberOfStrings;
        }
        char[] notes(){
            return stringNames;
        }
    }
}
```

File #2

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ViolinDriverGonzalezAP3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //Declare file and class names
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Java violinOutput.txt");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        Violin[] violinAmount = new Violin[10];
        //Create 10 violin objects
        for (int i = 0; i < violinAmount.length; i++){
            violinAmount[i] = new Violin();
            System.out.println(Violin.getNumberOfViolins() + " Violin");
            output.println(Violin.getNumberOfViolins() + " object:");
            violinAmount[i].tuneOff();
            output.println("The violin is now tunning...");
            violinAmount[i].tuneOn();           
            output.println("The violin is now playing...");
            violinAmount[i].startPlaying();
            output.println("String numbers is " + Violin.getNumberOfStrings() + " with String names are " + Arrays.toString(Violin.notes()));
            output.println("The violin is now stopped");
            violinAmount[i].stopPlaying();
        }
        output.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your numberOfViolins data member will never be anything but 1. You created it as an instance field instead of a class field.

Comment: If you're only starting with Java you shouldn't have classes inside other classes. Why did you define class Violin inside class ViolinGonzalezAP3?

Answer (score 0):

For creating an instance of inner class, you have to create an instance of outerclass initially. Check this code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ViolinDriverGonzalezAP3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        //Declare file and class names
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Java violinOutput.txt");
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
        ViolinGonzalezAP3 outerClassObj = new ViolinGonzalezAP3();

        ViolinGonzalezAP3.Violin[] violinAmount = new ViolinGonzalezAP3.Violin[10];
        //Create 10 violin objects
        for (int i = 0; i < violinAmount.length; i++){
            violinAmount[i] = outerClassObj.new Violin();
            System.out.println(violinAmount[i].getNumberOfViolins() + " Violin");
            output.println(violinAmount[i].getNumberOfViolins() + " object:");
            violinAmount[i].tuneOff();
            output.println("The violin is now tunning...");
            violinAmount[i].tuneOn();           
            output.println("The violin is now playing...");
            violinAmount[i].startPlaying();
            output.println("String numbers is " + violinAmount[i].getNumberOfStrings() + " with String names are " + Arrays.toString(violinAmount[i].notes()));
            output.println("The violin is now stopped");
            violinAmount[i].stopPlaying();
        }
        output.close();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification of the 2nd class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ViolinDriverGonzalezAP3 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    //Declare file and class names
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("Java violinOutput.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
    ViolinGonzalezAP3 vg = new ViolinGonzalezAP3();
    ViolinGonzalezAP3.Violin[] violinAmount = new ViolinGonzalezAP3.Violin[10];
    //Create 10 violin objects
    for (int i = 0; i < violinAmount.length; i++){
        violinAmount[i] = vg.new Violin();
        System.out.println(violinAmount[i].getNumberOfViolins() + " Violin");
        output.println(violinAmount[i].getNumberOfViolins() + " object:");
        violinAmount[i].tuneOff();
        output.println("The violin is now tunning...");
        violinAmount[i].tuneOn();           
        output.println("The violin is now playing...");
        violinAmount[i].startPlaying();
        output.println("String numbers is " + violinAmount[i].getNumberOfStrings() + " with String names are " + Arrays.toString(violinAmount[i].notes()));
        output.println("The violin is now stopped");
        violinAmount[i].stopPlaying();
    }
    output.close();
   }
}//end method main
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why the code returns `cannot resolve` error for the `Violin` class is due to the fact that the class has been defined as an inner class in `ViolinGonzalezAP3`.

While it is still possible to instantiate and reference the inner class in some other parts of your code, there should be a good reason for doing so. In your particular case I'd advise to avoid doing so and simply expose the Violin class as follows:

File: Violin.java

```
class Violin{

    private static int numberOfViolins = 0;
    private static final int numberOfStrings = 4;
    private static final char[] stringNames = {'E', 'A', 'D', 'G'};
    private boolean isTuned = false;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;

    //Create methods for Violin class
    public Violin(){
        numberOfViolins++;
    }
    public void startPlaying() {
        isPlaying = true;
        System.out.println(" violin is now playing.");
    }
    public void stopPlaying() {
        isPlaying = false;
        System.out.println(" violin has stopped playing.");
    }
    public void tuneOn() {
        isTuned = true;
        System.out.println(" violin is now tuned.");
    }
    public void tuneOff() {
        isTuned = false;
        System.out.println(" violin is untuned.");
    } 
    public static int getNumberOfViolins(){
        return numberOfViolins;
    }
    public static int getNumberOfStrings(){
        return numberOfStrings;
    }
    public static char[] notes(){
        return stringNames;
    }
}
```

Please look at this class in details as you'll find here a few more changes to your original code:

- All the class attributes have been made `private` to prevent direct access/modification other than via using public member methods
- `numberOfStrings` and `stringNames` parameters have been defined static final since they are constant and won't be modified
- `numberOfViolins` has been defined static to keep the global number of the violins created (note: there are better approaches to resolve this task, i.e. responsibility for keeping the number of instances can be moved to the `ViolinDriverGonzalezAP3`, but that will do for now).
- Methods `getNumberOfViolins`, `getNumberOfStrings` and `notes` have been defined as `public static` so they can be accessed as class methods via `Violin.<methodName>`

Comment: Thank you, those explanations help a lot to make file 1 better formatted.